# how to insert countdown timer in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

hii
I want to insert a countdown timer in my project. right now i am using the following code:

```
{

    DateTime dt = (DateTime)Session["end_t"];
    DateTime dt_curr = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan ts = dt - dt_curr;
    lblTimer.Text = ts.Hours.ToString() + ":" + ts.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + ts.Seconds.ToString();
    if (ts.Minutes == 0)
    {
        Timer1.Enabled = false;
        Response.Redirect("~/Online Exam/result2.aspx");
    }
```

the code works fine but when we move to some other page and then return back to main page the timer gets restarted.
How can i overcome with this? Please help

Comment: are you sure that you are not changing `Session["end_t"]`'s value anywhere? (maybe Page_Load)

Comment: the value of session comes from the page load only, here is the code from page_Load

DateTime end_time = start_time.AddMinutes(15);
Session["end_t"] = end_time;

Comment: Are you trying to limit users visiting time of website or each page?

Comment: basically it is an Online Examination app, so the timer is required when a user presses Start Test button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're resetting the end time on each page load, probably by doing something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime start_time = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime end_time = start_time.AddMinutes(15);
    Session["end_t"] = end_time;
}
```

Instead, you should store the end time only if the timer is not already running:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["end_t"] == null) {
        DateTime start_time = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime end_time = start_time.AddMinutes(15);
        Session["end_t"] = end_time;
    }
}
```

Comment: by adding the above code it thorws a NullReferenceException saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @Surbhi, can you specify which line throws the exception?

Comment: It throws this exception for about 4-5 times and on the next try the code runs perfectly and the timer is running fine now but now. Ex- the timer is showing 14:30 n on a button click, the timer stops, shows 14:30 for a few seconds and then shows correct time. How do I sync the timer perfectly that it doesn't stop on any user action.

Comment: @Frédéric the line which shows the exception is `DateTime dt = (DateTime)Session["end_t"];`

Comment: @Surbhi, maybe that line of code runs before we're setting the session value in `Page_Load()`? But in that case, you should get an error even without the change. Can you post more code so we can have a better idea of what's going on?

Comment: code for page_load
`if (Session["end_t"] == null)
{
DateTime start_time = DateTime.Now;
DateTime end_time = start_time.AddMinutes(15);
Session["end_t"] = end_time;
}`

code for timer
`DateTime dt = (DateTime)Session["end_t"];
DateTime dt_curr = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan ts = dt - dt_curr;
lblTimer.Text = ts.Hours.ToString() + ":" + ts.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + ts.Seconds.ToString();
if (ts.Minutes == 0)
{
Timer1.Enabled = false;
Response.Redirect("~/Online Exam/result2.aspx");
}`

Answer (score 0):

Make a Master page and make your operations with timer there.
or
You can send the counter of timer to next page then do same operations with timer there